# Flutter card dealing effect

Tags: flutter, flutter-animation

I'm looking to create a card dealing effect such that there's a deck of cards, then on click, it deals the cards unto a grid view (the card moves into position in the grid) in order for the user to play a memory game. It is very similar to a hero animation, except it is not a transition (or perhaps it is? I'm not sure)

Is there a way to do this in Flutter?

Comment: You can use https://rive.app/ to create complex animations.

Comment: rive.app seems a bit excessive for what I'm trying to accomplish, don't you think?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of trying to use a `GridView`, you could put your cards (a series of `Image` widgets, I assume) in a `Stack`, then use `AnimatedPositioned` widget to move it. For example:

```
  Stack(
    children: [
      AnimatedPositioned(
        duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 500),
        left: 20, // try change this to `0` and "hot reload"
        top: 20,
        child: FlutterLogo(),
      ),
      AnimatedPositioned(
        duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 500),
        left: 30,
        top: 30,
        child: FlutterLogo(),
      ),
    ],
  ),
```

Like the above code example, but instead of using hardcoded values such as 20, you can use a variable like `_slided ? 20 : 0`. Whenever you want the animation to occur, just toggle the boolean variable and call set state.

To make it more realistic, you can pass in `curve: Curves.easeOut` to the `AnimatedPositioned` widget, so the moving animation would go faster in the beginning and gradually slow down (like cards sliding on a table and gradually come to a full stop due to friction).

Comment: While this is a good solution, and indeed solves the issue if the number of columns were predefined, I would like the capability that gridview has which makes it responsive dependent on the width of the children. Is there a way to combine the two approaches?

Comment: @dor If you want to responsiveness, use `LayoutBuilder` to get the parent's constraints and then calculate the grid size yourself.